# Undefined index: unsigned

Tags: mysql, indexing, table

we are seeing

```
Undefined index: unsigned
```

coming from file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Helper/Abstract.php on line 310
```

I see the function `public function convertOldColumnDefinition($column)` is being called where later in the function it tries to access `$column['unsigned']` which apparently does not exist. But in which table? or query?

```
        $result = array(
        'type'     => $type,
        'length'   => $length,
        'unsigned' => $column['unsigned'],
        'nullable' => $column['is_null'],
        'default'  => $column['default'],
        'identity' => stripos($column['extra'], 'auto_increment') !== false
    );
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Put a log method in the function to get a backtrace from where it's called.